# ExtGWT - Populate Combo-Box from restful Service

Tags: java, gwt, rest, gxt

How I can populate comboBox with data from remote REST Service? Or for this task is better to use Advanced ComboBox?

Comment: Can't you just make a request to your service and then populate your ComboBox? Give some more details.